# How to fix my script. The missing part is I need my time stamp from Master sheet to show on my helper sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm looking for help to fix my script in google sheets posted below. The missing part is I need my time stamp (NewDate) from Heat Help Notifications (Master sheet) to show on my helper sheet. Any suggestions or fixes? Because the timestamp is being inserted by the script it's not "typed" so it's not showing on my helper sheet.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
    // sheet where the cells are protected from updates
    var masterSheetName = "Heat Help Notifications " 
    // sheet where the values are copied for later checking
    var helperSheetName = "Helper" 
    // only take into account edits on or below this row
    var firstDataRow = 1; 
    // only take into account edits on or to the right of this column
    var firstDataColumn = 1; 

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var masterSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    if (masterSheet.getName() != masterSheetName) return;

    var masterCell = masterSheet.getActiveCell();
    if (masterCell.getRow() < firstDataRow || 
        masterCell.getColumn() < firstDataColumn) return;

    var helperSheet = ss.getSheetByName(helperSheetName);
    var helperCell = helperSheet.getRange(masterCell.getA1Notation());
    var newValue = masterCell.getValue();
    var oldValue = helperCell.getValue();

    if (oldValue == "") {
        helperCell.setValue(newValue);
    } else {
        masterCell.setValue(oldValue);
    }

    var aCell = e.source.getActiveCell(), col = aCell.getColumn(); 
    if(col ==  1 || col ==  3 || col ==  5 || col ==  7 || col ==  9 || 
       col == 11 || col == 13 || col == 15 || col == 17 || col == 19 || 
       col == 21 || col == 23 || col == 25 || col == 27 || col == 29 || 
       col == 31 || col == 33 || col == 35 || col == 37 || col == 39 || 
       col == 41 || col == 43 || col == 45 || col == 47 || col == 49 || 
       col == 51 || col == 53 || col == 55 || col == 57 || col == 59 || 
       col == 61 || col == 63 || col == 65 || col == 67 || col == 69 || 
       col == 71 || col == 73 || col == 75 || col == 77 || col == 79 || 
       col == 81 || col == 83 || col == 85 || col == 87 || col == 89 || 
       col == 91 || col == 93 || col == 95 || col == 97 || col == 99 || 
       col == 101 || col == 103)  //checks the column
    var nextCell = aCell.offset(0, 1);
    if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date())
    var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "dd/MM/yyyy kk:mm:ss");
    adjacentCell.setValue(newDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give that a try,

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var masterSheetName = "Heat Help Notifications " // sheet where the cells are   protected from updates
  var helperSheetName = "Helper" // sheet where the values are copied for later checking
  var firstDataRow = 1; // only take into account edits on or below this row
  var firstDataColumn = 1; // only take into account edits on or to the right of this column

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var masterSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if (masterSheet.getName() != masterSheetName) return;

  var masterCell = masterSheet.getActiveCell();
  if (masterCell.getRow() < firstDataRow || masterCell.getColumn() <   firstDataColumn) return;

  var helperSheet = ss.getSheetByName(helperSheetName);
  var helperCell = helperSheet.getRange(masterCell.getA1Notation());
  var newValue = masterCell.getValue();
  var oldValue = helperCell.getValue();

  if (oldValue == "") {
   helperCell.setValue(newValue);
  } else {
   masterCell.setValue(oldValue);
  }

  var aCell = e.source.getActiveCell(), col = aCell.getColumn(); 
  if(col == 1 || col == 3 || col == 5 || col == 7 || col == 9 || col == 11 || col == 13 || col == 15 || col == 17 || col == 19 || col == 21 || col == 23 || col == 25 || col == 27 || col == 29 || col == 31 || col == 33 || col == 35 || col == 37 || col == 39 || col == 41 || col == 43 || col == 45 || col == 47 || col == 49 || col == 51 || col == 53 || col == 55 || col == 57 || col == 59 || col == 61 || col == 63 || col == 65 || col == 67 || col == 69 || col == 71 || col == 73 || col == 75 || col == 77 || col == 79 || col == 81 || col == 83 || col == 85 || col == 87 || col == 89 || col == 91 || col == 93 || col == 95 || col == 97 || col == 99 || col == 101 || col == 103)  //checks the column
   var nextCell = aCell.offset(0, 1);
   if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ){ //is empty?
     nextCell.setValue(new Date())
     var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
  "GMT-5", "dd/MM/yyyy kk:mm:ss");
     // Copied the code from above and changed masterCell to nextCell
     var helperCell = helperSheet.getRange(nextCell.getA1Notation());
     helperCell.setValue(new Date());
   }

}
```

Comment: That worked for me (I have full edit rights) but now other users who do not have full edit rights can not even edit the columns Ive given them edit rights to. For example I gave a user edit rights to Column C and D on the Heat Help Notifications sheet but its still like they only have view rights. I want them to be able to initial in column C and it auto stamps Column D. I do not want them to have edit rights to other users columns in that sheet nor edit rights to the helper sheet at all. Can you help please?

Comment: Firstly that is whole new question, so please start a new thread/post. Also, I cannot think of  any straight forward way to do what you ask.